# JavaScript nested object reference to parent

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I'm working on a fairly complex object in JS and I'm running into issues:

I have the following (abridged) code:

```
var LocationSelector;

LocationSelector = function(container) {
  this.selectors = {
    container: container,
    city_name: container.find('input.city_name'),
    city_id: container.find('input.city_id')
  };
  return this.initialize();
};

LocationSelector.prototype = {
  initialize: function() {
    return this.city.checkStatus();
  },
  city: {
    status: null,
    message: null,
    id: null,
    checkStatus: function() {
      if (LocationSelector.selectors.city_name.val() && LocationSelector.selectors.city_id.val()) {
        return LocationSelector.city.setStatus('success');
      }
    },
    setStatus: function(status) {
      return alert(status);
    }
  }
};
```

Two questions:

1) Inside of a sub-object function `this` no longer refers back to the root object. It seems I can refer back to the parent if I write out `LocationSelector.object.method( args )`, but that's a lot to type. Is there a way to define a shortcut back to the parent object?

2) In some situations I need to have several instances of this per page, so it's important to me that I can set the various `selectors` when a new object is instantiated and then refer to the instance selectors in the prototype. Is referring to the parent object (ie. `LocationSelector`) in sub-object methods even viable for that? How does JS know to stay with the currently active object's stored properties?

Basically, I'm trying to implement a class, and I'm totally new to JS and don't really know how to do it. So, any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your current approach. Here is something closer to what you want, although I do not understand why `LocationSelector` instances have a `city` member.

```
function LocationSelector(container) {
  this.selectors = {
    container: container,
    city_name: container.find("input.city_name"),
    city_id: container.find("input.city_id")
  };

  this.city = new City(this);
  this.city.checkStatus();
}

function City(locationSelector) {
  this.status = null;
  this.message = null;
  this.id = null;
  this.locationSelector = locationSelector;
}

City.prototype.checkStatus = function () {
  if (this.locationSelector.selectors.city_name.val() && this.locationSelector.selectors.city_id.val()) {
    this.setStatus("success");
  }
};

City.prototype.setStatus = function () {
  alert("status");
};
```

Things to note:

1. Data properties go on the instance, not the prototype. Only methods go on the prototype.
2. `City` is clearly its own class, so you should make it one. In your code, a single city is being shared between all instances of `LocationSelector`, since it is put on the prototype. In this code, it is assigned as an instance property, in the `LocationSelector` constructor.
3. You cannot reference `LocationSelector.selectors` like you do in your example. `LocationSelector.selectors` would be for "static" properties, which `LocationSelector` does not have. Instead you need to refer to the `selectors` property on specific instances; in this example, that instance is given by `this.locationSelector`.
4. Points 2 and 3 speak to an important fact: the "child" `City` instance cannot reference to properties of the  "parent" `LocationSelector` class without having a concrete instance of it.

---

Here is a version of the code that makes more sense to me, removing the part where `LocationSelector` has a `city` property (which it doesn't use).

```
function LocationSelectors(container) {
  this.city_name = container.find("input.city_name");
  this.city_id = container.find("input.city_id");
}

function City(locationSelectors) {
  this.locationSelector = locationSelector;
}

City.prototype.checkStatus = function () {
  if (this.locationSelectors.city_name.val() && this.locationSelectors.city_id.val()) {
    this.setStatus("success");
  }
};

City.prototype.setStatus = function () {
  alert("status");
};

function checkCityStatus(container) {
  var locationSelectors = new LocationSelectors(container);
  var city = new City(locationSelectors);

  city.checkStatus();
}
```

---

I leave you with a link to [Crockford's "Private Members in JavaScript"](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html), which talks about doing OO in JavaScript. There are other, probably better explanations out there, but at least that one will put you on the right track.

Comment: The reason for the City member is that this handler needs to do a whole lot of stuff, so in my original use case (only ever 1 handler per page) I found it easier to create this as an object literal with many nested properties so I could do things like: `LocationSelector.city.setStatus(...)` and `LocationSelector.district.changeName(...)` and `LocationSelector.errorMessages.display(...)`... and so on. Each sub-object was related to a chunk of the DOM, each of the pieces interacts with the others, and LocationSelector is really like a namespace that binds them together...

Comment: ... Now that I have a situation where I need more than one per page I have to learn how to do it with handler objects that can behave as distinct instances. I'm a total newbie when it comes to JS so this is really stretching what I know. Anyway, your answer is *extraordinarily* helpful and shows exactly what I needed: both a basic patch showing how my code is broken and a recommendation for a smarter approach. Thank you very much, if I could give you 5 upvotes I would.

Answer (score 2):

Read about [Closures](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/) and I'm positive you will find what you need.

Here's is a quick example of what you are trying to accomplish:

```
function MyCoolObject(name){
   var self_myCoolObject = this;
   this.name = name;
   this.popAlertWithNameInFiveSeconds = function(){
       setTimeout(function(){
         alert('Incorrect reference to name "this.name" returns ' + this.name);
         alert('Correct reference to name "self_myCoolObject.name" returns ' + self_myCoolObject.name);
       },5000)
   }
}

//TO TEST
var MyObj = new MyCoolObject('MySuperCoolName')
MyObj.popAlertWithNameInFiveSeconds();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of JS code that I have. Before I drop down into a click handler, I make a reference to the object (`SlideShow`) by calling `var parent = this`. Then in later nested functions, you can be sure you're calling the right scope by using `parent.function()`

```
/* Slide Show object */
function SlideShow(parentContainerId) {

    this.BEGINNING  = 'Beginning';
    this.END        = 'End of list';
    this.FIRSTINDEX = 0;

    this.length     = jQuery(parentContainerId + ' img').length;
    this.container  = jQuery(parentContainerId);
    this.imgs       = jQuery(parentContainerId + ' img');
    this.index      = this.FIRSTINDEX;
    this.status     = 'beginning';           // beginning, end



    this.init = function() {
        // get it started
        this.moveTo(this.FIRSTINDEX);
        this.process();

        // ****GET OBJECT SCOPE*****
        var parent      = this;

        // set up click listener
        this.container.find('img').click(function(e) {
            var item_width = jQuery(this).width();
            var x_click_ps = e.clientX - jQuery(this).offset().left;
            var x_diff     = x_click_ps / item_width;




            console.log(this);
            if (x_diff < .5) {
                parent.moveByIncrement(-1)
                parent.process();
            } else {
                parent.moveByIncrement(1);
                parent.process();
            }

        });
    }


.
.
.
}
```